# Better way to do [linux] system & environment validation?

Tags: linux

Is there a better way to do environment validation?  Usecase is a virtualized environment nearing 300 servers created by someone else, and need to validate before accept them (i.e. before I install custom software and find issues after-the-fact).

These are all currently done manually with a paper checklist

- ssh to a linux server [ this is so the following tests are run from the box ]
- for each server it communicates with:

  - ping -c 20 X target servers that the linux server is expected to communicate, review packet loss and RTT avg/max/deviation
  - telnet  target servers to make sure the appropriate ports are open and accessible for the services they offer (i.e. 1433 sql server, 3306 mysql, 80 webservice, 25 smtp)
- nslookup to make sure the server is setup on the DNS.

Is there a better way to do system validation?

These are all currently done manually with a paper checklist

- ssh to linux server
- `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to review if cpu core count and clock speed are what was requested
- `df` to check diskspace allocated
- `free -m` to check memory amount

Are there examples of a better approach, such as setting expected values or ranges in the checks then simply run 'all' tests for pass/fail checking?

Comment: An environment with 300 systems should really come with management tooling more advanced than a printout. My condolences.

Comment: looking for 'actionable' answers.  This question which only tackles an example of nslookup shows that simple answers are insufficient: http://superuser.com/questions/812664/nslookup-command-line-with-a-record-ip-as-sole-output

Comment: Please provide more clarity around what it means to validate a system. For example, when you say "ssh to a linux server" are you checking to see if a particular username and password works? Or do you just want to know that TCP port 22 is open? Same goes for telnetting to the other services you mentioned. When checking latency, what potential problems are you trying to flush out?

Comment: Consider Ansible for this. http://www.ansible.com/

Comment: Ansible seems more for configuration, not validation (the boxes are created and configured by a different group, and the intent of the question is how to validate if the implementation is as expected).

Comment: @dhartford Dig a little deeper. Ansible is, at its core, for doing reproducible tasks against multiple servers. You can use it to set up a server, but you can also use its various modules to validate setup. Ping, check installed packages, make HTTP requests, ensure ports are active, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several years later, but the answer I was looking for was found in:

http://www.ansible.com

> gather_facts: true

Since ansible is natively agentless via ssh, this already tackled the ssh access need.

The gather_facts feature already got a lot of the needed data of the target system, just a matter of evaluating it (example for diskspace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981907/using-ansible-to-manage-disk-space ).

I've not evaluated ansible for the networking/firewall requirements from the target system, but looks very doable!

Comment: Almost four years later and you came back to share your solution.  Thanks for that.  Also, if you endured ~4 years of the manual approach... bless your soul for that!  My only wish is that you had found Ansible sooner.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: script it.

Longer answer: All of the tests you mention above can be automated through simple OS tools. As an example, the `ping` command can be run, then the return code checked and used to determine pass/fail status. It will take a bit more time to create the script, but it will save significant time running through all 300 of your machines to be tested.

Comment: Is there a reference location that may provide some examples of how to script and use a return code?  Not looking for someone to write it, but for each command there is a lot to figure out...when starting from nothing, a template/starting place would be great

Comment: I tend to assume people working in professional IT capacities already have the ability to script, or at least have the ability to Google for the references they need...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what you listed, 
I also recommend the following checks to include in the bare minimum:

- List of open ports: make sure that only the necessary ports are open and nothing else
- List of installed packages should match your predefined list, no extras
- List of user accounts should match your predefined list, no extras
- List of groups *and* their members should match your predefined list, no extras

> Are there examples of a better approach, such as setting expected values or ranges in the checks then simply run 'all' tests for pass/fail checking?

Some of the checks may need a definition of acceptable fault rate.
For example when checking the available disk space,
most probably the values won't be exactly the same on all servers,
so your check will need a threshold of acceptable level.
Similarly, a few missed pings may be acceptable,
so instead of requiring 100% returned pings,
a validation for > 95% might be more practical.
On the other hand, for some things you should have zero tolerance,
such as the list of open ports.

With 300 servers to check, paper-based methods will not work.
By the time you finish checking all the machines,
some might have already failed quietly.
So yes, you have to script it.
It shouldn't be too hard to piece it together.
Create something that somewhat works and if you get stuck ask on [UNIX SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for help.
Once you have something fully working, you can ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for further optimization and cleaning.

It's definitely worth investing in scripting this,
so that you can easily rerun the tests to check the health of your server farm.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a linux server I would try and use nmap to scan the network, it can then report back to you what servers are responding and what services are running on them. 
keep in mind this scan could cause some potential issues ( depending on the services running on the servers you are scanning ) and you should get consent from the servers owners before running it.